# Create table and change <td> background color using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, random, numbers

My task is this: I want to create a page with the button and a horizontal table of results from 1 to 20.

When you click a button, you get a random number, display it on a page and the cell with this number should change color to green. If the number appears for the second time, make it grey.

If the cell is already grey, nothing happens. That's it this is [my code](http://jsbin.com/mazove) plth helpm me if you can. thanks

Comment: Link the code or at least create a snippet code integrated to your question in order to know where you error is or what you did so far.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/mazove

Comment: This reads like a little requirements spec, not a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `if` to check if the area is already green, or grey, and decide what to do accordingly:

```
      if(!numbs.getElementsByTagName("td")[i].getAttribute("class")) {
        numbs.getElementsByTagName("td")[i].setAttribute("class", "green");
      } else if(numbs.getElementsByTagName("td")[i].getAttribute("class") == "green") {
        numbs.getElementsByTagName("td")[i].setAttribute("class", "grey");
      } else {
        // do nothing.. 
      }
```

View [JSFiddle](http://jsbin.com/waxadupucu/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

ps: you're hardly using jQuery, mostly vanilla JS.

Comment: thanks friend, i am beginner at this time

Answer (score 1):

you can use am if statement on the on click

```
<td onclick:"checkClass(this)"></td>/*Example of your td*/

function checkClass(this){
    /*check if class element is already green*/
    if($(this).attr("class")=="green")
    {
      /*if so them change to gray*/
      $(this).attr("class","gray") ; 
    }
    else if($(this).attr("class")=="gray")
    {
     /*do noting*/
    }
    else
    {
      /*first time you click set green*/
      $(this).attr("class","gray");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function cheack(){  
  var randNumb = (Math.floor(Math.random()*20)+1);
  var numbs = $(document).find('td')[randNumb];
  var c = $(".green").index("td");

  if ((!$(numbs).hasClass('green')) && (!$(numbs).hasClass('grey')))
    {
      $(numbs).addClass('green');
    }
else
  {
    $(numbs).addClass('grey');
  }

}
```

http://jsbin.com/rubomehura/1/